# Create Polyline Feature From Table Using arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a table contains list of coordinates for different polylines in this format (LineID, X, Y)

I want to convert the list to polyline feature and I thought of using xy to line tool then dissolve tool but it returns and error saying that the input feature for dissolve tool does not exist or not supported

below is my code

```
import arcpy
#Determine Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
path = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
#Choose Input Table
inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Output Feature Class
outfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

#Assign Fields To Create Lines
startX = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
startY = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
endX = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
endY = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
lineID = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
Geodesy = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)

#Create Initial Line Features (Not Merged)
arcpy.XYToLine_management(inTable,'oulines.shp', startX, startY, endX, endY,'', lineID, Geodesy)

#Run Dissolve To Merge Features With Identical IDs
DissolveInput = path + '\outlines.shp'
arcpy.Dissolve_management(DissolveInput, outfc, lineID)
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Model Builder. The tool you want is `arcpy.PointsToLine_management(inshp, outshp, Line_Field='lineID', Sort_Field='')`. See here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm